# HTML Select option with PHP Dynamic

Tags: php, html

I'm getting a weird result when i try to implement the PHP inside a HTML

The config is literally my DB connection, other scripts work well but only for this matter i couldn't figure out.
Maybe I missed out some elements.

```
<select name="country">
    <option value="" disabled selected style="display: none;">All Japan Cities</option>
    <?php
    include 'scripts/config.php';
        $query = "SELECT state FROM product";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $count = count($result);
        if (!empty($count)) {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {              
                $state = $row['state'];                                                
                echo "<option value='$state'> $state </option>";
            }
        } else {
            echo '<option>No data</option>';
        }
    ?> 
    </select>
```

I keep on getting no data for my select statement where I have 3 results in my db.

Comment: is the database connection already established in this file?

Comment: Warning
`mysql` extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used

Comment: Can you var_dump() the result? Is it empty?

Comment: @Ann-SophieAngermüller, yes , my other script are working fine when it comes for insertion and selection .. just this HTML

Comment: @MaKobi, yeap.. i even tried echoing my $query and no luck.

Comment: @FreedomPride yeah but are these insertions eg in the same file? if not you have to select a db and stuff like that

Comment: What was the result of echoing? Is it empty?

Comment: @MaKobi, it's empty :(

Comment: what about a `var_dump($result)`?

Comment: @WasteD, no luck.. even echoing is not writing on the HTML also.

Comment: W8 var_dump has to give a result at least NULL

Comment: @WasteD, i'm going to try to do it at the header `<?php echo PHP_VERSION; ?>`

Comment: Better use `phpinfo()`.

Comment: @WasteD, no luck.. okay this is seriously bugging me... a simple echo couldn't display ..

Comment: So I think it is a Problem where I can't help because I am to inexperienced for that... I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do a `count()` on a mysql result set like that.

Try using `mysql_num_rows` instead, like this:

```
....
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if (!empty($count)) {
....
```

Also, as others have said, these old `mysql_` functions are deprecated, so you should probably switch to mysqli or PDO if that is practical as well.

Comment: no luck on it too :( , still triggering the no data part.